# How do you use blacklist_values an match all fields in the logstash-filter-prune plugin?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

My log messages contain a bunch of key/value pairs. I use `kv` to specify a list of keys to keep. However, I need to exclude keys which do not have a value. For this, I am using `gsub` to change an empty value into `notset`. Now I want to use `prune` to blacklist these values. I wasn't aware that you need to specify each field name individually with `prune`. Is there a way to match all fields? If I add new fields in the `kv` section, I do not want to touch the `blacklist_values` hash again.

Here is an example Logstash filter configuration:

```
filter{
  mutate {
    gsub => [ 'message', '= ', '=notset ' ]
  }
  kv {
    include_keys => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
  }
  prune {
    blacklist_values => [ "??", "notset" ]
  }
  ...
}
```